# Magento 2 set updated_time through query

Tags: magento2, query

I want to update column "updated_time" through query but it is not working. Where I am wrong?

```
$where = ['entity_id'  => (int)$customerData,

                 ];


        $connection->update(
        $tableName,
        array("updated_at" => 'UTC_TIMESTAMP()'
              ),
        $where
        );
```

How can I update this field?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Connection()->update(
$object->getResource()->getTableName($tableName),
['updated_at'=> UTC_TIMESTAMP()],
['entity_id = ?' => (int)$customData]
);
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to do this through query only.

Comment: @akshaybillore i have edited my ans please check

Comment: No not working.